# Getting a strange error while trying to build a code formatter inside google sheet api

Tags: google-sheets-api

I have a huge google sheet with some code I'm storing for Blind 75 challenge and I'm trying to add a macro to the sheet so that any coded solution that will be added - it will be highlighted like notepad++ (code blocks is not supported in Google Sheet).

This is the code I was able to write and it covers only the "class" and "def" keywords in python, I'm sorry in advance - it's the first time I'm using the google-sheets-api.[This is how my google-sheets looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbDcs.jpg)

```
function myFunction() {

    var doc = DocumentApp.create('Test Document');
    var body = doc.getBody();

    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C2:C2");
    var blueColor = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
      .setForegroundColor("##0303fc")
      .build();
    var purpleColor = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
      .setForegroundColor("#871f78")
      .build();

    var values = range.getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        code_str = values[i]
        const result = code_str.toString().split('\n');
        if (result)
        {
          for (var row = 0; row < result.length; row++) 
          {
            if (result[row].toString().startsWith('class') || result[row].toString().trim().startsWith('def'))
            {
              var changeFunc = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
                .setText(result[row])
                .setTextStyle(0, 10, blueColor)
                .build();
            }

            console.log(changeFunc)
            
            range.setRichTextValues([
              [changeFunc]
            ]);
            
          }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property setRichTextValues on object SpreadsheetApp.Range.
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing script and your image and your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Yes, and thanks in advance, I'm trying to automatically detect the code in the celles and change the font formating and coloring accordingly like any IDE or Code Block addon

Comment: Your English is completely ok, thanks for responding  My script is going over column C where I'm putting code into those cells and I'm trying to change the color of some keywords like 'class' and 'def' so that they can be highlighted like in the IDE

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I saw your sample image, it seems that at the column "C", the color of some keywords like 'class' and 'def' has already been changed. Do you want to retrieve the color from the column "C"?

Comment: I'm doing it manually,  it's so slow that I want to automate it 

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `I'm doing it manually, it's so slow that I want to automate it`, is your showing image the sample output situation? If my understanding is correct, can you provide the sample input situation?

Comment: Yes.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1edSb2P2mwEXl-8vFkCtnK-mJzYKmvhAVWawwrpMyfHw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't see your URL. Can you confirm it again?

Comment: Sorry, I was on vacation, I changed it to edit permissions 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1edSb2P2mwEXl-8vFkCtnK-mJzYKmvhAVWawwrpMyfHw/edit?usp=sharing